# How to fix 'Error: Could not find or load main class' on scala application in Intellij?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I tried to make a simple scala application, Page Rank, and I can't run it.

The source from which I got the code : https://github.com/abbas-taher/pagerank-example-spark2.0-deep-dive

I created a new scala project in Intellij, the package com.scalaproj and added the code from the source into the scala object, SparkPageRank. I also added the external jars for spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7, as it said in the tutorial.

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// scalastyle:off println
package com.scalaproj

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/**
 * Computes the PageRank of URLs from an input file. Input file should
 * be in format of:
 * URL         neighbor URL
 * URL         neighbor URL
 * URL         neighbor URL
 * ...
 * where URL and their neighbors are separated by space(s).
 *
 * This is an example implementation for learning how to use Spark. For more conventional use,
 * please refer to org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.PageRank
 *
 * Example Usage:
 * {{{
 * bin/run-example SparkPageRank data/mllib/pagerank_data.txt 10
 * }}}
 */
object SparkPageRank {

  def showWarning() {
    System.err.println(
      """WARN: This is a naive implementation of PageRank and is given as an example!
        |Please use the PageRank implementation found in org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.PageRank
        |for more conventional use.
      """.stripMargin)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: SparkPageRank <file> <iter>")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    showWarning()

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("SparkPageRank")
      .getOrCreate()

    val iters = if (args.length > 1) args(1).toInt else 10
    val lines = spark.read.textFile(args(0)).rdd
    val links = lines.map{ s =>
      val parts = s.split("\\s+")
      (parts(0), parts(1))
    }.distinct().groupByKey().cache()
    var ranks = links.mapValues(v => 1.0)

    for (i <- 1 to iters) {
      val contribs = links.join(ranks).values.flatMap{ case (urls, rank) =>
        val size = urls.size
        urls.map(url => (url, rank / size))
      }
      ranks = contribs.reduceByKey(_ + _).mapValues(0.15 + 0.85 * _)
    }

    val output = ranks.collect()
    output.foreach(tup => println(tup._1 + " has rank: " + tup._2 + "."))

    spark.stop()
  }
}
// scalastyle:on println
```

I builded the project with no errors, but when I tried to run it, it said :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.scalaproj.SparkPageRank
```

I also tried this in Eclipse, the same error. Can someone tell me what to do?

[Here you can see the folder tree of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9u4I.jpg)

Comment: Try object SparkPageRank extends App

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: What is your folder tree like ? Have you declared the scala folder as a source folder ?

Comment: Yes, it is the source folder, it is the only class I have, anyway. I will edit and post a picture of the folder tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the error. You just have to mark the directory containing your SparkPageRank object as Sources root in Intellij. (the directory must be in blue)

Right click on the directory -> Mark Directory as -> Sources Root

Hope this work for you !

======= Update after discussion ======

Since this Solution is not working, You have to create a maven project, And add spark and scala dependencies. In github link, I am not sure that your code work without a pom.xml, or build.sbt.

======= Update of 11/13 =======

Code worked with build.sbt

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: How did you add your project to IntelliJ ? I see that you are downloading it from github ? Did you use command line ?

Comment: I didn't download it, I created my new scala project in Intellij, the package and the object, and then I copied the code from the source and I pasted into my new created scala object.

Comment: Are you using maven or sbt ?

Comment: May ben you can just try to create a project from github directly

Comment: It is not usefull, because it only has the scala object, without any packages

Comment: Dependencies? What dependencies? I only added the external jars of spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7, as it said in the tutorial.

Comment: You have to create a maven project and add all spark dependencies, for your spark objects, i.e: sparkSession and etc...

Comment: The code works with build.sbt, sorry I messed them up, I never worked with scala projects and I'm a little confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202259/discussion-between-driss-nejjar-and-ana-c).